$\Lambda^n(M)$ is not isomorphic to $C^{\infty}(M)$ if M is not orientable
Let $M$ be a differentiable Manifold of dimension n. If $M$ is orientable, then there exists an $\omega \in \Omega^n(M)$ (top-degree differential form) such that $\omega(p) \neq 0$ $ \forall p \in M$.
If $M$ is orientable then $C^\infty(M) \cong \Omega^n(M)$ as $C^\infty(M)$-modules, via

$f \mapsto f\omega$

for a non-vanishing $\omega$.
My question is:

If there exists no non-vanishing differential form, is $C^\infty(M)$  not isomorphic to $\Omega^n(M)$?

Clearly in this case the latter map from $C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \Omega^n(M)$ is not an isomorphism, but can we show that there can't exist an isomorphism?

Careful. If you consider spaces of sections, then your isomorphism is between $\Omega^n(M)$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$, as $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-modules. If you consider vector bundles, then it is between $\Lambda^n(M)$ and $M\times \Bbb R$, as vector bundles over $M$. The distinction is important and fundamental, and you are mixing them

Thank you for pointing that out, here i'm refering to sections as $C^{\infty}$ modules.

Assume that $\Omega^n(M)$ and $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ are isomorphic as $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-modules. Let $\varphi : \mathcal{C}^\infty(M) \rightarrow \Omega^n(M)$ be an isomorphism and $\omega = \varphi(1)$.
Since $M$ is non orientable, then necessarily, $\omega$ vanishes at some point $x \in M$. Let $\alpha$ be an $n$-form that doesn't vanish at $x$ (it always exists). By surjectivity of $\varphi$, there is a smooth map $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(f) = \alpha$.
By linearity, $\alpha = f\omega$, which is a contradiction at point $x$.
Notice that we didn't need the injectivity assumption on $\varphi$ so more generally, there is no surjection $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M) \twoheadrightarrow \Omega^n(M)$.
